# How can I drop a table whose name is "logs/#sql-ib203" that appeared after a MySQL crash?

Tags: mysql, sql, innodb

`DROP TABLE logs/#sql-ib203` does not work due to `/`:

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near '/#sql-ib203' at line 1

The table `logs/#sql-ib203` appeared after a database crash (not enough disk space while re-indexing and deleting some attributes in a table in the `logs` database). `SHOW TABLES` does not list the table `logs/#sql-ib203`, but when trying to `ALTER` the table that was being changed during the crash MySQL complains about the existence of the table `logs/#sql-ib203`:

> ERROR 1050: Table 'logs/#sql-ib203' already exists
>
> SQL Statement:
>
> ALTER TABLE `logs`.`srv_logs` DROP COLUMN `filenum` , DROP COLUMN
>   `agent` , DROP COLUMN `ip` , DROP COLUMN `event_source`

I use MySQL 5.6.12-winx64 and InnoDB.

Answer (score 1):

Try to execute:

```
DROP TABLE `logs/#sql-ib203`
```

Need to wrap the name with ``, that should drop it.
Regards.

Comment: Thanks, it seems to be the correct syntax, but apparently the table is kind of ghostly: `Error Code: 1051. Unknown table 'logs.logs/#sql-ib203'`. I tried with `DROP TABLE `#sql-ib203``, `DROP TABLE `/#sql-ib203`` and `DROP TABLE `sql-ib203``, I get the same `Unknown table` issue. (respectively `Error Code: 1051. Unknown table 'logs./#sql-ib203'`, `Error Code: 1051. Unknown table 'logs.#sql-ib203'` and `Error Code: 1051. Unknown table 'logs.sql-ib203'`). Interestingly none of these error codes display `'logs/#sql-ib203'`, which is the table name MySQL complains it exists when I try to do ALTER.

Comment: You now have a .(dot) in name `logs.logs/#sql-ib203`, try to see what is correct there. maybe create new schema and tables as they where, if it isn't real time used

Comment: create new schema, and than create table samename as (select * from oldschema.samename) ... and add all tables you need, and leave that log behind :D

Comment: Hmm any idea how I can check what is correct? `SHOW TABLES` does not list `#sql-ib203` or anything similar. There used to be a file `#sql-ib203`, which I deleted it (I use `innodb_file_per_table`). Yeah I'm already creating a new schema, but it is a bit intellectually disappointing :-) But thanks for pointing out the right syntax for weirdly named tables, that's good to know!

Comment: No problem, it is weird. Check the content of the `ls -lh /var/lib/mysql/<schema name>`, you should have .frm of all your tables in that schema. if you delete it everything in there with that name it should be gone

Comment: Maybe InnoDB create different extension of binary file

Comment: Yep, I've checked it, nothing. Maybe be a ghost of `#sql-ib203` still reside in the main `ibdata1`, but I don't want to screw all my databases. `InnoDB` creates `.ibd` and `.frm` files for each table when `innodb_file_per_table` in on like in my case.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can do a dump of your database, the orphaned innodb temporary table is not referred in the dump file, then you can drop the database and restore again.
2. Also you can try ; drop table `#mysql50##sql-ib203`;

Reference : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/identifier-mapping.html

Comment: You can avoid that much of downtime. Instead of dumping the tables you can `RENAME` them. See https://twindb.com/resolving-error-1050-42s01-at-line-1-table-already-exists/